# Transition table from state truth table

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, truth-table

Assuming a simple binary state variable allocation can be made and that any unused states can be treated as don’t cares. How would I Design  a corresponding transition table for this  system including flip-flop (D- FF) inputs and system inputs/outputs.
(I am unsure why the table looks so weird outside of the editor its my first time using this).
Here is the State table:

| State | Clock | A | B | C | R1 | Y1 | G1 | R2 | Y2 | G2 | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S0 | 5s | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | S1 |
| S1 | 6s | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | S2 |
| S2 | 80s | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | S3 |
| S3 | 6s | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | S4 |
| S4 | 5s | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | S5 |
| S5 | 6s | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | S6 |
| S6 | 80s | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | S7 |
| S7 | 6s | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | S0 |

I have tried this 3 times and got it wrong three times any help would be greatly appreciated.

My attempt:

| State | D0 | D1 | C0 | C1 | R1 | Y1 | G1 | R2 | Y2 | G2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| S1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| S2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| S3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| S4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| S5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| S6 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| S7 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

(D0 and D1) represent the binary state variable allocation.
(C0 and C1) represent the system inputs/outputs.

Comment: How would i design a transition table from this state table?

Comment: looks like a homework assignment

Comment: its a self project assignment since I'm studying electronics alone I have done the Karnaugh and VHDL myself I also built the logic system but I cant get the excitation or transition maps correct and I don't know where I am going wrong

Comment: Edited with my try of the transition table

Comment: Seems that these are traffic lights ...

Comment: yes they are traffic lights ns ew traffic lights i got this project from a book called Computer Organization and Architecture An Introduction by B. S. Chalk it was one of the last few projects and i just cant build the transition table or excitation map since i don't understand those concepts at all the i don't know how to take this data and apply it to a d flip flop that's why i am asking for help (step by step help if possible) but the answer would also be appreciated as the book doesn't include any answers to any problems given

Comment: You can note also that "states" are the numbering of an "up-counter". And R1Y1G1 ... are just a "combination" of each state (can be each synthesized by a multiplexor).

Comment: You need just do the "table transition" with "actual" state (first column) and the future state (last column) of the "state table". And then apply D-FF rules ( need 3). Timers not used.

Answer (score 0):

See [this note](https://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eademosth/E757/Topic6.pdf) for reference.

So, the problem is "synthetizing" a "counter" ... with D-FF, and you need 3 D-FF.
Your second table is not what you are "searching" ...

...

When "counter" will be synthesized ...,
you should be able to draw a circuit like this (this is only the beginning ... and a "fast" version.

Only the first "light" is drawn (R1). You should do the same for other lights.
NB: the timing is not included, only the "sequence". Should use also some timers.
The 74151 is used as a "general" function of 3 variables (can be "extended").

[image]